# Button ActionListeners in loops

Tags: java, swing, loops, jframe, jbutton

I have started programming (in general) 4 days ago, so I'm still quite a noob :P Also, my code is probably gonna be unreadable :/

Idea behind the program: I input a few words (from a language I want to learn) and these words are put into an ArrayList. I then press a button to write the whole ArrayList to a file and the second part of the program becomes relevant.

Now, this is where I need your help.

I want to set a JLabel to a random string of my ArrayList (I did that with

`Random rand = new Random();
int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(wort.size());
JLabelWordAsked.setText(wort.get(randomIndex));` (wort is my ArrayList) which works so far.

I have made two buttons, an "I knew it" and an "I didn't know it". "I knew it" should remove the string I set JLabelWordAsked to (wort.get(randomIndex)) from wort and then reset the JLabel to a new random string of wort.
"I didn't know it" should just reset the JLabel to a new random string of wort.
Repeat that until wort is empty or the button "Stop" is pressed and then writeToFile(); (which writes the content of wort to a file, this works  already.)

I tried to do that like this:

```
while (!wort.isEmpty()) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomIndex;
        randomIndex = rand.nextInt(wort.size());


        btnGewusst.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



                wort.remove(randomIndex);
                lblWortabfrage.setText(wort.get(randomIndex));
                zuLernen();

            }
        });

        btnNichtGewusst.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                lblWortabfrage.setText(wort.get(randomIndex));
            }
        });

    }
```

which sadly doesn't work. (It did for my console version of the program, though :( ) 
How would you guys do that?
Here's the source code of the whole program: http://pastebin.com/egnUzZQe
note: JLabelWordAskes is lblWortabfrage, "I knew it" is btnGewusst, "I didn't know it" is btnNichtgewusst and zuLernen() just puts all strings from wort into one string zuLernen.

Comment: Don't use `Abusive/Offensive` language !!

Comment: Better? :) @NeerajJain

Comment: Get rid of the loop, this is not how GUIs work, they are event driven and tend to not work in a linear fashion

Comment: What do I write to get my desired result then? That's the reason why I posted this question @MadProgrammer

Comment: You write in some kind of method, which you can call in response to some other event/change, like the user typing a character

Comment: Can you give me an example?  @MadProgrammer